# How to save text file in firebase hosting using firebase functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I want to generate sitemap from firebase db using firebase functions.

The last step would be saving the generated xml file somewhere near to the index.html to give the relative path to the google.

How i can save the xml file in firebase function to the firebase hosting path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to manipulate the contents of a Firebase Hosting site. So you can't save a file to a hosting path directly.

Instead there is an integration between Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions that allows your Cloud Functions code to be called for specific URLs that you specify. The result of the function is then stored in the Firebase CDN, and cached according to the headers you specify. You could generate your sitemap in such a Cloud Function.

To learn more about this approach, read the [Firebase Hosting documentation on the integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

Comment: Thanks @Frank Van

Comment: The easier way i found is to invoke fb function using onCreate api for a new node on the path and update the sitemap.xml
Then upload the updated/generated xml file to the storage 
We can use download url of the file in the storage as sitemap url

Answer (score -1):

Just grab your sitemap in xml format from any sitemap creator website. After that you will see that there are two folders when you `firebase init`. One is functions & other is public.
Put the xml file in public folder. It will be uploaded with other files when you run command `firebase deploy`.